# Howto 16bit left logical shift all ip addresses in CSV file (octets 3&4 become 1&2)

Tags: python, perl, bash, sed, awk

I'd like to do a 16 bit logical left shift on all IP address in a CSV file (thosands of rows)

## Example

(octets 3&4 become 1&2)

```
172.22.200.5 -> 200.5.0.0   (octect #1 [172] and octect #2 [22] were shifted away)
10.1.1.0 -> 1.0.0.0         (octect #1 [10]  and octect #2 [1] were shifted away)
```

Each row will always have an IP address in field #4 and #5

2014-01-24 12:10:39.760,760,0.000,**10.1.40.27,10.1.40.2**,17,40424,514,502000,2000,......,0

## Before

```
2014-01-24 12:10:39.760,760,0.000,10.1.40.27,10.1.40.2,17,40424,514,502000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:07.760,760,0.000,172.14.40.37,1.127.40.2,17,57278,514,558000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:42.760,760,0.000,10.1.40.250,10.1.40.2,17,42347,514,500000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:07.760,760,0.000,1.168.40.37,192.13.40.2,17,57278,514,558000,2000,......,0
```

## After

```
2014-01-24 12:10:39.760,760,0.000,40.27.0.0,40.2.0.0,17,40424,514,502000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:07.760,760,0.000,40.37.0.0,40.2.0.0,17,57278,514,558000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:42.760,760,0.000,40.250.0.0,40.2.0.0,17,42347,514,500000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:07.760,760,0.000,40.37.0.0,40.2.0.0,17,57278,514,558000,2000,......,0
```

I am processing the csv file on linux and am fine with bash, sed, awk, perl, python, etc. to resolve the issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you even try ? This looks like some homework to me.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it appears to be a request for someone else to write the code or explain how to write the code, and does not identify a specific problem or question about programming. Please include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differed from the expected results, and any error messages you received. Please read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This isn't homework and yes I tried but only knew how to do a perl -pi -e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IPv4 address is simply a 32-bit number. Each part represents one of the bytes. A 16-bit shift is a two-byte shift, so `a.b.c.d` becomes `c.d.0.0`. As such, all you need is

```
$ip =~ s/^\d+\.\d+\.(\d+\.\d+)\z/$1.0.0/;
```

You could use a real CSV parse to extra the correct field, or you can fudge it.

```
s/^([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,)\d+\.\d+\.(\d+\.\d+),\d+\.\d+\.(\d+\.\d+)/$1$2.0.0$3.0.0/;
```

It looks like you could even get away with

```
s/,\d+\.\d+\.(\d+\.\d+)(?=,)/,$1.0.0/g;
```

As a one-liner:

```
perl -pe's/,\d+\.\d+\.(\d+\.\d+)(?=,)/,$1.0.0/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

bash only

```
shift_ip() {
    local -a octets
    IFS=. read -a octets <<< "$1"
    printf "%d.%d.0.0\n" "${octets[@]:2}"
}

IFS=,
while read -a fields; do
    fields[3]=$( shift_ip ${fields[3]} )
    fields[4]=$( shift_ip ${fields[4]} )
    echo "${fields[*]}"
done <<END
2014-01-24 12:10:39.760,760,0.000,10.1.40.27,10.1.40.2,17,40424,514,502000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:07.760,760,0.000,172.14.40.37,1.127.40.2,17,57278,514,558000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:42.760,760,0.000,10.1.40.250,10.1.40.2,17,42347,514,500000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:07.760,760,0.000,1.168.40.37,192.13.40.2,17,57278,514,558000,2000,......,0
END
```

```
2014-01-24 12:10:39.760,760,0.000,40.27.0.0,40.2.0.0,17,40424,514,502000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:07.760,760,0.000,40.37.0.0,40.2.0.0,17,57278,514,558000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:42.760,760,0.000,40.250.0.0,40.2.0.0,17,42347,514,500000,2000,......,0
2014-01-24 12:12:07.760,760,0.000,40.37.0.0,40.2.0.0,17,57278,514,558000,2000,......,0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b/$1.0.0/g' infile > outfile
```